# SuperWebSocket ClearIdleSessionInterval vs IdleSessionTimeout

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

So Im not sure I understand the difference between these to confi-options in SuberWebSocket.
Is the ClearIdleSessionInterval only an option of how often superwebsocket checks for timed out sessions or what?
If I set the ClearIdleSession = false would that let my session live forever (assuming theyre not forcefully closed) no mather what the ClearIdleSessionInterval or IdleSessionTimeout is set to?

Grateful for any insight or help anyone can provide since googling and checking the docs doesnt give me anything.

Only docs on it on SuperWebSockets hompepage:

```
clearIdleSession: true or false, whether clear idle sessions. Default value is false.

clearIdleSessionInterval: the clearing timeout idle session interval. Default value is 120, in seconds.

idleSessionTimeOut: The session timeout period. Default value is 300, in seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to use `clearidlesession` with `idlesessiontimeout`. If we don't use both together it will clear the session even though it is not idle. So make sure you use both together if you want to clear idle session.

I was facing the same issue and clearing out the active sessions too.

Example:

```
IdleSessionTimeOut = 35,
ClearIdleSession = true,
ClearIdleSessionInterval = 35
```

Thanks,
Veena